# Which tag should we use? [ouran-high-school-host-club] vs [ouran] vs [ohshc]

Tags: discussion, retagging

I just asked a question that was about Ouran High School Host Club. The tag for that did not exist before so I tagged it as [ohshc](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ohshc), which is one way that it is commonly known. It is also commonly known as [ouran](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ouran), but the technical correct tag from the name would be [ouran-high-school-host-club](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ouran-high-school-host-club). That seems a bit too long, though. What should we put it as?

Comment: That's what synonyms are for. Use the full series name as the main tag, and have synonyms pointing the acceptable names to it.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha [tag:ouran-high-school-host-club] is 27 characters, so it doesn't fit in the 25 character limit. Hence full English series name isn't an option.

Answer (score 5):

To avoid confusion and lets try [ouran-koukou-host-club](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ouran-koukou-host-club), since it fits,

We should only abbreviate if the title is way too long.

Like for [oreimo](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oreimo), *Ore no Imouto ga Konnani Kawaii Wake ga Nai* (*My Little Sister Can't Possibly Be This Cute*).

We had a similar issue with the English title of *A Certain Scientific Railgun* so we used the romanized name [toaru-kagaku-no-railgun](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toaru-kagaku-no-railgun).

Comment: Since "ouran-high-school-host-club" fits in a tag, should it be a synonym?

Comment: @Eric I count 27 characters. The limit is 25.

Comment: Also, Ouran HSHC is apparently an official abbreviation in English. The Funimation YouTube videos use it, e.g. [Episode 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-_9T9nDgpY8), so maybe we should have a synonym [tag:ouran-hshc].

Comment: @LoganM Oh, I didn't think spaces counted. But yeah, that's probably not a bad idea.

Comment: @Eric I just checked, and spaces do count.